# OR " || " opreator not working in if statement in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and wants to shwo the js code only if following condition true

```
<?php 
if(($this->uri->segment(1)!='reports') || ($this->uri->segment(2)!='manageflyers' && $this->uri->segment(3)!='save')){?>
    //some js code
<?php }?>
```

But i does not work please help where i am making the mistake.

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: can you describe condition in which condition you want to show js code?

Comment: i want to show js code when not reports,not manageflyer, and not save words show in my url like

Comment: localhost/reports

Comment: could  you provide the values for 
$this->uri->segment(1)
$this->uri->segment(2)
$this->uri->segment(3)

Comment: localhost/mangeflyer/save

Comment: it is codeignter bult in function

Comment: @smehsoud:  
*i want to show js code when not reports,not manageflyer, and not save words show in my url like*

then you should use && and not ||

Comment: these are separate condition not one AND it is like you want to be not banana in basket,not mango in basket,not apple in basket and some other fruit be in basket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of `!=` with an OR `||` will always equal true because that string variable will only equal one thing and not be the other

so your code will work like this

```
<?php 
if(($this->uri->segment(1)=='reports') || ($this->uri->segment(2)=='manageflyers' && $this->uri->segment(3)=='save')){ 
    //do nothing
 }else{
    //some js code
 }
```